# Streaming a section of video to an external display

Tags: video, processing, windows

I want to be able to connect an external display to my Windows PC (in addition to the existing one), and stream a selected portion of the screen to this display. For example, if I have a small terminal window open on my main monitor, then this smaller display will show only that terminal window, not the rest of my desktop. I guess it's like Picture In Picture (PIP) on a TV, but for a PC instead.

Can anyone recommend the easiest way to achieve this? I don't mind getting into the video programming side of it (maybe using DirectShow?), but if there is a hardware solution, eg on a DSP board,then that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably off-topic, because the easiest way to achieve this is to use the tools already provided by your graphics card.

Mirror your display, adjust the resolution of your screen to that of the window, and pan the screen until the desired area is displayed.

If you want to be able to select an arbitrary window to be mirrored, you need to add this functionality to your window manager, which is impossible on Windows (but should be doable for most Linux window managers).  If you want to do this with an app you're developing (or an open-source terminal), just use a second display.

Answer (score 0):

would a usb display work? http://www.mimomonitors.com/products/mimo-720-s  it may be easier then trying to stream part of the window and sending it to a display.

the other option i can see working is if you have a second vga or DVI port and adding a cheap LCD monitor to clone or extend your desktop

not trying to be discouraging but what you want to do would require you to create a PC program to send that part of the screen ( not sure how in SW) and a communication line like a serial port or usb to control your display.

Edit: after rethinking the whole issue, I would still use a prebuilt solution, but if you want something from scratch, you could get an ARM processor(cortex-Mx) add a LCD screen (your choice on resolution) and build an API so you can send straight data to draw the screen through the com port(rs232 serial) or use Ethernet connection.

Comment: Software part of screen capture depends on a few variables, but there are ways, [C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fw1kt6f9.aspx) providing some of the easiest. Using the linked method I got between 1 and ~100 FPS capture rate, depending on monitor settings (16 bit color sped it up a lot)

Comment: I do agree that a prebuilt solution would be most ideal

Answer (score 0):

Your graphics card driver can put windowed video played in a video player to some external monitor or TV in full screen. If we are not talking about video, but just a window of some software application running on your pc, then you can use [UltraVNC](http://www.uvnc.com) and share just that single window for displaying on remote pc.